# Validate user login using CMembership.ValidateUser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was reading about `Membership.ValidateUser`.

this is how you implement it;

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text))
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UsernameTextbox.Text, NotPublicCheckBox.Checked);
```

I want to validate a user if his/her username is `paul` and the password is `123`. By using `Membership.ValidateUser` i don't think i can do that validation. Please explain what `Membership.ValidateUser` does and how can i validate a user if he provides the correct credentials ?

Comment: What do you mean you dont think you can do that validation? What is the specific issue here? The MSDN for this method pretty much covers what you have already mentioned : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, i have visited that page, but i am not sure where the database logic is. How does the method know how to compare the username and password ? i am a newbie